# How to return html content without escaping in serializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have model with TextField that contains html. 
Let's say I have a row that contains `<a href="http://googke.ru">google</a>` in `TextField`. 
The API returns `"<a href=\"http://googke.ru\">google</a>"`.

How can I remove `"` escaping?

Comment: which API? you can use `mark_safe`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe

Comment: Hey, @dimazurbik I was wondering, did you found my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`html`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html) module, which has a method named `escape`:

> ```
> html.escape(s, quote=True)
> ```
>
> Convert the characters &, < and > in string s to HTML-safe sequences. Use this if you need to display text that might contain
>   such characters in HTML. **If the optional flag quote is true, the
>   characters (") and (') are also translated;** this helps for inclusion
>   in an HTML attribute value delimited by quotes, as in `<a href="...">`.
>
> New in version 3.2.

Let `s` be: `s = '<a href="http://example.com">example</a>'` then:

```
from html import escape

html_line = escape(s)
```

Now the `html_line` contains the `s` string without any 'escaping', looking like this:

```
&lt;a href=&quot;http://example.com&quot;&gt;example&lt;/a&gt;
```

---

If you want to keep the characters `< > &` etc. but avoid the escaping of `"`, you can utilize the other method of the [`html`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html) module, called `unescape`:

```
from html import unescape

html_line = unescape(s)
```

Now the `html_line` will look like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com">example</a>
```